# BigQuery - Lookup sum for previous month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to lookup the sum of clicks for the query for the previous month, for example if my data looks like:

| date | query | clicks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | test | 1 |
| 2020-02-01 | test | 2 |
| 2020-02-02 | test | 3 |
| 2020-02-02 | test | 5 |
| 2020-03-01 | test | 5 |
| 2020-03-01 | test | 6 |
| 2020-03-02 | test | 5 |
| 2020-03-02 | test | 6 |

Im looking to develop a query that will look somthing like:

| mmYY | query | clicks | clicks_prev_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-2020 | test | 11 | - |
| Feb-2020 | test | 22 | 11 |

ive tied a few window funtions via a sun query to group by month/year/query but i cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation with window functions:

```
select date_trunc(date, month) as yyyymm, query, sum(clicks) as clicks,
       lag(sum(clicks)) over (partition by query order by min(date)) as clicks_prev
from t
group by yyyymm, query;
```

Comment: Probably `lag(sum(clicks))` was meant instead of `lag(clicks)`